# How do I put a PayPal donation button in the About Box of my Windows application?

Tags: windows, paypal, donations

Paypal has a lot of support for accepting donations from web pages -- I've been all over their site reading the details.

But what about a donation link from the about box of my good, old-fashioned Windows desktop application?

I'd like to put a donation graphic and link in my About Box.  I'd rather not have to embed a browser control, but would just like to create a simple link to PayPal.

Do they support this?  Is this doable?  If so, anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those questions you feel embarrassed about asking.

Here's how you do it:

1. Set up the link for your web page.
2. Go to your webpage and click on the link
3. Copy the resulting URL
4. Use that URL as the destination for your About Box link or whatever.

ShellExecute in Windows works nicely to go to a given URL.